# Read message up to % character

Tags: c++

I have a char array:

```
char arr[] = "%RED**dsa0x0%xcа%wq233SSS%(dsa........";
```

The array must be read from the `%` sign to the next `%`. That is, the message begins with `%` and has an unknown length (there can be no `%` in the middle of the message).

Here is the code:

```
void SaveMessToVec(const string& str)
{
    tail = tail + str;
    if (tail.empty()) return;
    assert(tail[0] == 0x24);
    while (true)
    {
        size_t f = tail.find(0x24, 1);
        if (f == string::npos) return;
        string message = tail.substr(0, f);
        //cout << message << '\n';
        vecForAP.push_back(message);
        tail.erase(0, f);
    }
}
```

However, my controller can't work with `string` and `vector`. How to rewrite this code to use only `char`?

Comment: Can your show us the code you've written?

Comment: Please pick one language. C is not C++ and C++ is not C. The solution will be different in the two, even if `std::string` is out

Comment: I guess it should be c++, because C has no "vectors".

Comment: StackOverflow isn't a place to go if you want somebody to do your homework for you.

Comment: You wrote that you can't use strings or vectors, but I see both there. Can you try to solve the problem without?

Comment: @Caleb you are right. I wrote with string, but my controller can't work with string and vector. and need to re-write with char

Comment: please explain why you cannot use `std::string` and `std::vector` in the quesiton. If you cannot use other parts of the standard library too, thats relevant

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 my controller cannot work with standard string or vector (I dont know why). I tried, but didn't work/

Comment: You might want to specify the desired API of your code - API is half of the solution. If you don't specify it, people might come up with their own API, which might be inconvenient for you to use. If you cannot write API, that's also fine; maybe mention that in the question explicitly.

Comment: What do you want to happen to the messages once they're identified? Your function doesn't return a value, and it's only parameter is `const`, so it's not clear what the function is supposed to do.

Comment: you can extract a C string from a std::string using the .c_str() member function.  If you do need to convert the code consider strtok() to split a C string into smaller strings using % as the delimiter.

Comment: You know that 0x24 is not the ascii value of %, right?  https://www.google.com/search?q=0x24+hex+to+ascii+character

Comment: @Caleb I think he means to use global variables for the vector and the tail variable.  Here is an MVCE using his function verbatim: https://onlinegdb.com/SJk2KHH2w

Comment: @JerryJeremiah The OP explicitly said he can't use `string` or `vector`. We shouldn't have to guess at the desired output of the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can use vector and string you can use this function.

```
std::vector<std::string> split(const std::string& s, char delimiter) {
    std::vector<std::string> tokens;
    std::string token;
    std::istringstream tokenStream(s);
    while (std::getline(tokenStream, token, delimiter)) {
        if(token.size()!=0)
            tokens.push_back(token);
    }
    return tokens;
}
int main() {
    std::string str = "%RED**dsa0x0%xcа%wq233SSS%(dsa";
    std::vector<std::string> vec = split(str,'%');
    for(auto &v : vec)
        std::cout << v << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

If you cannot use string and vector you can use `strtok()`. `strtok` can tokenize a char array

```
int main() {
    char arr[] = "%RED**dsa0x0%xcа%wq233SSS%(dsa";
    char* token = strtok(arr,"%");
    while(token != NULL) {
       std::cout << token << std::endl;
       token = strtok(NULL,"%");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

How you tried to do this is not the appropiate way to tokenize a string. But if you want to do this way I show you a solution for you.

I do not understand your whole code procisely but maybe this would be good enough for you.

```
vector<string> vecForAP; // global variable to store data for you
void SaveMessToVec(string& str) {
    str.erase(str.begin()); //because the first letter is %
    while (true){
        size_t f = str.find('%');
        if (f == string::npos) {
            vecForAP.push_back(str);
            return;
        }
        string message = str.substr(0,f);
        vecForAP.push_back(message);
        str.erase(0, f+1);
    }
}
```